# Data in columns and rows, one record in one cell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have this:

```
<% @devices.each do |device| %>
<tr>
<td>
    <% if device.photo.exists? then %>
    <%= image_tag device.photo.url(:small) %></br>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to device.name, device %></br>
    <%= device.description %></br>
    <%= link_to 'Redaguoti', edit_device_path(device) %></br>
    <%= link_to 'Ištrinti', device, :confirm => 'Ar tikrai norite ištrinti šį prietaisą?', :method => :delete %>
</td>


<% end %>
```

I want to get data like this:

[image: table]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at `in_groups_of`? From the API [Array Methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of)

If I understand you question, this should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Use each_with_index instead of each. This way, you can also get the index, like 1,2,3.. and do whatever you want with it.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001511

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap each cell in `<td>` & `</td>`.  Drop the `<br>` tags, they create new lines, not new cells.

Basically, inside your loop, you create a `<tr>` to make your row, then `<td>SOME DATA</td>` for each cell, then close the `</tr>`.

```
<% @devices.each do |device| %>
<tr>
<td>
    <% if device.photo.exists? then %>
    <%= image_tag device.photo.url(:small) %></br>
    <% end %>
</td>
<td>
    <%= link_to device.name, device %>
</td>
<td>
    <%= device.description %>
</td>
<td>
    <%= link_to 'Redaguoti', edit_device_path(device) %>
</td>
<td>
    <%= link_to 'Ištrinti', device, :confirm => 'Ar tikrai norite ištrinti šį prietaisą?', :method => :delete %>
</td>
</tr>

<% end %>
```